# Why Twisted resource.Resource execute render() twice?

Tags: python, twisted

Im new to Twisted. Why is it printing "render()" twice? I know if I return server.NOT_DONE_YET, it will only print once, but I wish to return string/JSON instead. Any help?

Code:

```
from twisted.web import resource, server
from twisted.internet import reactor
import simplejson

class WResource(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf=True

    def __init__(self):
        print "resource started"

    def render(self, request):
        print "render()"
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return simplejson.dumps(dict(through_port=8080, subdomain='hello'))

reactor.listenTCP(9000, server.Site(WResource()))
reactor.run()
```

Output:

```
> python server.py
resource started
render()
render()
```

Comment: I tested using 2.6.6 and twisted 10.2.0. It works as expected (printed once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your web browser is requesting `favicon.ico`.  If you print `request.postpath` in your `render` method, you'll see that only one of the requests is hitting the page that you expect.

Comment: @MickeyCheong Which brower you are using? I am using Firefox